# Export sklearn predictions to a CSV file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, export-to-csv

You can find below the code I use to export sklearn predictions to a CSV file. As you can seee I make predictions from a CSV. Everything works fine but the output I get with the returned CSV file does not display data correctly:

Part of the Code:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\testimport.csv"
file = open(path, newline='')
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader) #la 1ere ligne correspond au titre
data = []
id_trajet =  []
for row in reader:

    track_id  = int(row[0])
    duree =  float(row[1])
    distance = float(row[2])
    vr_gauche = float(row[3])
    vr_droite = float(row[4])
    acc = float(row[5])
    freinages = float(row[6])
    data.append([duree, distance, vr_gauche, vr_droite, acc, freinages])
    id_trajet.append(track_id)


prediction = clf.predict (data)

#print(prediction)

returns_path = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\testexport.csv"
file = open(returns_path, 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(["Id_Trajet", "Type_Conduite"])
writer.writerow(id_trajet)
writer.writerow(prediction)


print(prediction)
```

---

What I get right now with the CSV file is:

```
Id_Trajet,Type_Conduite
357,666
intermediaire,sportive
```

What I would like to get from the CSV file:

```
Id_Trajet,Type_Conduite
357,intermediaire
666,sportive
```

I do not sort data correctly. Could you please him me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Pandas DataFrame for data manipulation and export.

```
import pandas

id_trajet = [357, 666]
prediction = ['intermediaire', 'sportive']

df = pandas.DataFrame(prediction, columns=['Type_Conduite'], index=id_trajet)
df.index.name = 'Id_Trajet'

print(df.to_csv())
```

output:

```
Id_Trajet,Type_Conduite
357,intermediaire
666,sportive
```

Comment: You awesome it worked. Thanks for your much appreciated help!

Comment: I used this logic to export the data into excel for a multilbel classifier - predicting 10 class_labels, it prints on the screen exactly how the OP requested. However, when I take this into csv it only exports the last label output. My code is as below                            
ypreddf = pd.DataFrame(prediction, columns=['Prediction'], index=X_testlist)
ypreddf.index.name = 'X_testlist'
ypreddf.to_csv('results.csv') How to append the results of each label after the previous label predictions please?